# How stopping a progress dialog after Sync?

Tags: java, android

I made a progress dialog that I would like appeared during synchronization. The code that starts the synchronization is this

```
if(check.isDeviceConnected())
{
    Sincro = new Synk(this);
    Sincro.start();
    ProgressDialog myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
}
```

I tried to put `myDialog.dismiss();` after the brace, but the app crashes with a Java `Null Pointer Exception` in line where it is `myDialog.dismiss()`. Why? How do I make it disappear after Sync?

Comment: That would depend on whether the `Synk` class returns from `Start` directly, or after the sync is done, and/or if it has a callback that tells when it's complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create a variable for ProgressDialog
ProgressDialog myDialog = null;
if(check.isDeviceConnected())
{
    Sincro = new Synk(this);
    Sincro.start();
    //initialize your dialog
    myDialog  = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
}

//use this where you want to dismiss

myDialog.dismiss();
```

Let me know if your problem solved..

Comment: Won't this just dismiss the dialog the millisecond after it has been created? (if it doesn't crash using the nullpointer already mentioned in the question)

Comment: This will throw `NPE` if `check.isDeviceConnected()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Try with-

```
 if(myDialog!=null)
   myDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` (as you are redefining  the variable again)because of the scope of `myDialog` is only till if condition and the variable you have declared globally is assigned as null. Instead try

```
if(check.isDeviceConnected())
{
    Sincro = new Synk(this);
    Sincro.start();
     myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
}

myDailog.dismiss();// where ever you wish to dismiss
```

Comment: If the variable was not in scope, there'd be a compilation error, not a runtime error.

Comment: Does not work! In my Synk class i put in onFinish method  if(myDialog!=null)
   myDialog.dismiss();

But it doesn't work..I'm going crazy..Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog myDialog;    


if(check.isDeviceConnected())
 {
   Sincro = new Synk(this);
   Sincro.start();
   myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
 }

inside your sincro class create an onFinish like function:

 onSyncComplete(){

   if(myDialog!=null){
       myDialog.dismiss();
    }

 }
```

Comment: In the class Synk I put:  public void onFinish() {
     if(myDialog!=null){
        myDialog.dismiss();
     }
But it doesn't work! The ProgressDialog is always "active"
 }

Comment: onFinish() of android will be called at the very end of the activity life cycle.. call the  function onSyncComplete() at the end of your sync.   If you use [asyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) Things will be very easy and you wont have to worry about all this.

Comment: If I put only onSyncComplete () eclipse gives me error. If I put onSyncComplete void () does not. Anyway, it does not work. The Progress Dialog is always active